# How to associate models correctly cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a scenario where  i have templates which has many themes.
Clear enough that my relation will be **template hasmany themes**
I wanna show the template with number of themes and i am applying this code:

```
$this->Template->recursive = 2;
     $this->Template->bindModel(
                         array(
                          'hasMany' =>array(
                            'TemplateTheme'=>array(
                               'className'=>'TemplateTheme',
                               'fields'  => 'count(TemplateTheme.id) AS themes'
                           )
                          )
                      ),false
   );
   $this->paginate = array(
                      'order' => array('Template.modified DESC'),
                      'limit' =>$limit
                    );   
     $template = $this->paginate('Template');
     pr($template);die();
```

but i am getting is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Template] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => churchDesign
                    [status] => Active
                    [created] => 2011-10-24 10:37:23
                    [modified] => 2011-10-25 15:16:46
                )

            [TemplateTheme] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [template_id] => 1
                            [TemplateTheme] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [themes] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Template] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => blossoms
                    [status] => Active
                    [created] => 2011-10-19 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2011-10-24 14:05:27
                )

            [TemplateTheme] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

The problem here is it is counting all the themes in first array(1st template).see [TemplateTheme] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [themes] => 3
                                            )
the third theme actually belongs to the 2nd template.The relation is

template_id is in themes table to represent each theme for a template.

Template 1 has 2 themes and template 2nd has one theme and currently its showing all the three themes in the first template.

i want it like this way

```
templatename1
count of themes 1st template

template name 2
count of themes of 2nd template
```

Please tell me the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to get the count of the Themes per each Template, the most elegant way is to use [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count).

Another way is to use Containable behavior, which fetches only the related data which you wish, and then count the fetched data array in PHP.
After you attach the containable behavior to the Template model, some code like this should work:

```
$allTemplates = $this->Templates->find('all', array(
                      'contain' => 'TemplateTheme.name'
                 ));
foreach($allTemplates as $template){
    $currentThemeCount = count($template['TemplateTheme']);
    foreach($template['TemplateTheme'] as $theme){
         echo $theme['name'];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone along the way.

Answer (score 0):

you can count the themes array like

```
foreach($template as $t){
    count($t['TemplateTheme'])
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Problem is not counting the themes.Problem is getting the themes for each template.Template one has 2 themes and template 2nd has 1 theme it is showing all the three themes in the first template.Thanx for your attention mentes..

Comment: try this  `$this->Template->bindModel(
           array(
                 'hasMany' =>array(
                 'TemplateTheme'=>array(
                 'className'=>'TemplateTheme',
                 'fields'  => array(                                 'count(TemplateTheme.id) AS themes','another_field'
                           )
                          )
                      ),false
   );´

Comment: Problem is not counting mentes problem is getting the correct data

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the find('count') method instead of using a virtual 'count' field like you're doing now. For example:

```
$allTemplates = $this->Template->find('all');
foreach($allTemplates as $data) {
    $templateCount = $this->Template->TemplateTheme->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'TemplateTheme.template_id' => $data['Template']['id']
        )
    ));
    // $templateCount should now contain the count of this specific template. Foreach will continue recursion for all others.
}
```

Comment: Isnt there a way to join the models like we do in custom joins?